# 登録フォームを作成する際の登録済みメールアドレスの確認

Tags: html, mysql

HTMLで登録フォームを作成する際に、MySQLのデータベースに登録済みのメールアドレスの場合「そのメールアドレスは登録済みです」とフォーム上で表示したいのですが、どうすればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score -2):

お客様が直接操作する web UA (IE とか chrome とか Firefox とか) と
web server (Apache httpd とか IIS とか) だけで実装するのは困難です。

普通は web server 側に middleware (HTML を動的生成するソフト) を設けて
その middleware がデータベースをアクセスし、
・登録済みメールアドレスなら「登録済みです」という HTML を動的生成
・未登録メールアドレスなら「登録できました」という HTML を動的生成
することになると思います。お客様の web UA はその HTML を表示するだけ。

middleware として何を使えばよいかとかは別の質問を上げていただくと幸いです。